# What's the best way to call someone who delivers small packages at the door?

Tags: word-choice, questions

What term for he/she will sound best?
Delivery boy?
Delivery person?
Delivery men?
Deliverer?
Courier?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you using the term? Are you talking to them or about them?

Comment: I'm talking about them, but interested in knowing the best to call them too, please

Comment: You are raising a sensitive and interesting issue.  My suggestion  is a personal rather than an expert view.  We want to avoid a job name that avoids gender, if possible.  That rather rules out 'delivery something'.  So there is a strong case for preferring the word courier, even though it stretches the meaning .  It is genderless and has the '-er' ending that indicates role.  'Deliverer' sounds odd, because we have long used it in the sense of 'rescuer'.  'Courier' stretches the basic meaning slightly, but not fatally.

Comment: Thank you @Tuffy. Your comment helps me! I think using "courier" term will be more appropriate. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is for the US.  If the package is delivered by UPS (United Postal Service), then I'd say

> UPS delivered my package today.

Or I might say "the UPS guy" -- because UPS delivery people are generally men.  I'm not sure I've ever seen a female UPS delivery person.  However it's easy to gender-neutralize this as "the UPS driver."

If it's delivered via United States Postal Service (USPS), then the traditional term was "mailman," but now, since there are plenty of female mail deliverers, it's common to say "mail carrier."

Note, I wrote *deliverers* but this would be awkward to pronounce, so it would be very unusual to hear this in conversation.

In densely populated areas, a small package might be delivered by a "courier."  For example, from one law office to another, maybe just a couple of blocks away.  Also for somewhat larger distances, there are "bicycle messengers" (who ride like maniacs -- and they'll be the first to admit it).

The most general term would be "delivery person."  However, in many contexts, one could say "delivery service."  Note that private, local *delivery services* would probably only be found in large cities.

Forget "delivery boy."  It's actually rather hard for teens to get jobs in most places in the US nowadays.  For a job held by an adult, "boy" would be inappropriate in general.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer was what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A *delivery boy* is rare in my experience these days; they were once employed in some businesses to deliver small items, but they are no longer common. A *delivery man* would be possible, but suggests to me an adult male delivering larger items. I have not heard *delivery person*, but I would interpret it as a non-gender-specific variation of *delivery man*.

A *deliverer* is usually somebody who saves or rescues (delivers) another. If you use it you are likely to be misunderstood.

A *courier* is both a person who collects items for delivery elsewhere, and a person who delivers them. As collection of items usually happens at a business, if you were speaking in a domestic context most people would understand the word to mean a person delivering small items.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations! It was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

A *mail courier* delivers packages and traditional mail.

Comment: Isn't that a carrier?

Comment: Or [mail carrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_carrier)

Comment: @YosefBaskin Not in the UK. We have postmen (or *postal workers*) and couriers.

Comment: Good catch! To your point, "Parcel carrier services deliver small parcels to customers. Courier services provide a wider ranger of services."